# language translation and migration

Tags: magento2.2, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

I've used the data migration tool to move from magento 1.6.2 into magento 2.2.7

I've some issues (mainly on backend) where it seems as if magento doesn't properly put text, instead it displays curly braces as the following image.

[image: problem with text]

Any ideas on what is going on?

Thanks.