# What tables contain customers + products information?

Tags: magento2, database

after a data migration problem (please check [language translation and migration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/300247/language-translation-and-migration) if interested on issue) I thought on alternatives.

a) Export csv with products + clients and reimport on clean install.

b) Export / import database tables that contain customer information + product information.

I'm gearing towards b for speed. What tables do I have to export + import?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the entire **customers** in the below tables.

```
SELECT * FROM `customer_address_entity`;
SELECT * FROM `customer_address_entity_datetime`;
SELECT * FROM `customer_address_entity_decimal`;
SELECT * FROM `customer_address_entity_int`;
SELECT * FROM `customer_address_entity_text`;
SELECT * FROM `customer_address_entity_varchar`;
SELECT * FROM `customer_entity`;
SELECT * FROM `customer_entity_datetime`;
SELECT * FROM `customer_entity_decimal`;
SELECT * FROM `customer_entity_int`;
SELECT * FROM `customer_entity_text`;
SELECT * FROM `customer_entity_varchar`;
SELECT * FROM `customer_grid_flat`;
SELECT * FROM `customer_log`;
SELECT * FROM `customer_log`;
SELECT * FROM `customer_visitor`;
SELECT * FROM `persistent_session`;
SELECT * FROM `wishlist`;
SELECT * FROM `wishlist_item`;
SELECT * FROM `wishlist_item_option`;
```

and you can find the entire **products** in the below tables.

```
SELECT * FROM `cataloginventory_stock_item`;
SELECT * FROM `cataloginventory_stock_status`;
SELECT * FROM `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx`;
SELECT * FROM `cataloginventory_stock_status_tmp`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_product`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_product_index`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_product_index_tmp`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_compare_item`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_bundle_option`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_bundle_price_index`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_bundle_selection`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_bundle_selection_price`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_bundle_stock_index`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_gallery`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_int`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_text`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_eav`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_eav_idx`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_eav_tmp`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_idx`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_price_tmp`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_tier_price`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_index_website`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_link`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_link_attribute_int`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_option`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_option_price`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_option_title`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_option_type_price`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_option_type_title`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_option_type_value`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_relation`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_super_attribute`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_super_attribute_label`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_super_link`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_website`;
SELECT * FROM `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category`;
SELECT * FROM `downloadable_link`;
SELECT * FROM `downloadable_link_price`;
SELECT * FROM `downloadable_link_purchased`;
SELECT * FROM `downloadable_link_purchased_item`;
SELECT * FROM `downloadable_link_title`;
SELECT * FROM `downloadable_sample`;
SELECT * FROM `downloadable_sample_title`;
SELECT * FROM `product_alert_price`;
SELECT * FROM `product_alert_stock`;
SELECT * FROM `report_compared_product_index`;
SELECT * FROM `report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily`;
SELECT * FROM `report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly`;
SELECT * FROM `report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly`;
SELECT * FROM `report_viewed_product_index`;
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! How did you manage to check out all needed relationships?